# Node js sequelize table not found

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get data like below

```
User.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
    // Table created
    return User.create({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Hancock'
    });

});

var users = User.findAll().then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'node.users' doesn't exist
```

But table exists in the database. I cannot find what is the issue.

Could anyone help to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define your `User` model?

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol Yes